# C# casting to nullable type?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, casting, clr

**Beyond** the regular boring difference between `Cast` and `As`

- if i *know* that *apple* is a *Fruit* so I can use `(Fruit)apple` - and it throws an exception if it aint
- `as value` can be checked against null to see if succeeded [won't throw Exception...]

However Ive been reading @EricLippert [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx) about this and there was a nice sample about Nullable Value Types :

```
short? s = (short?)123;
int? i = s as int?;
```

this *won't* compile...

<sub>Cannot convert type 'short?' to 'int?' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion</sub>

**Fine.**

so why this :

```
    short? s = (short?)123;
    int? i = (int?)s;
```

**Does** Compile ? ( *Against ALL Expectations* ! I **KNOW** that `s` is not  `int?`  - and it should go BANG but it aint ...)

the Cast checking here should be much more deadly than the former example (which went Bang)

I feel bad asking about this much-talked subject.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you described exactly what Eric Lippert wrote - the cast would compile while the `as` operator won't for cases regarding nullable types.

Comment: @Yahia but are we agree that short is NOT INT ?

Comment: short is not int BUT can be cast/converted to int - and that is what you are telling the compiler: make this short an int.

Comment: @Yahia Cast checking should be much more deadly...thats his job...to throw exception.......?

Comment: Why ? You are explicitley telling the compiler to use any way it knows to accomodate you... if it does not find a way it throws...

Comment: And one more thing - `int? i2 = (object)s as int?;` - actually returns `null`

Comment: Ok, I think I've figured out what you're asking... Let's try this: it's not `(int?)`'s job to throw when `s` isn't an `int?`. Its job is to throw if `s` isn't _convertible_ to an `int?`. There are _many_ cases where `(type)`-style casting can do things other than just testing whether you've got that type (for example you can even define your own--http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4(v=vs.100).aspx). If you really want to test to see if what you have is an actual instance of a type, you should use the `is` operator.

Comment: Or in other words, in the first example, `s as int?`, you're trying to convert `s` itself. In the second example, `(int?)s`, you take the _value_ of `s` and try to convert that. Does it make sense like that?

Comment: @MrLister Are you telling me that `(int?)s` is a value operation  ( as opposed to [as] which is reference operation ) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, your paraphrase of MrLister is pretty close to correct. It runs the risk of being confusing, however, because "value" and "reference" here don't have anything to do with C#'s value vs reference types.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Try to compile `int i = 123 as int;` and the error will be "The as operator must be used with a reference type ('int' is a value type)". `int i = (int)123;` on the other hand, will compile perfectly fine.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your first example, the `as` operator attempts to use the object `s` as an `int?`. Since `int?` isn't anywhere in the inheritance chain of `short?`, this operation fails.

In your second example, you're actually creating a new `int? i` with the value from `short? s`. This is a more generous operation, because it doesn't have to preserve the original `s` object on the left hand side.

**The important point here is that `as` isn't allowed to do anything that doesn't preserve your object's identity. An explicit cast can.**

Here's what the C# standard says about how the `(int?)` form works:

> 6.1.4 Implicit nullable conversions
>
> Predefined implicit conversions that operate on non-nullable value
>   types can also be used with nullable forms of those types. For each of
>   the predefined implicit identity and numeric conversions that convert
>   from a non-nullable value type S to a non-nullable value type T, the
>   following implicit nullable conversions exist:
>
> ·         An implicit conversion from S? to T?.
>
> ·         An implicit conversion from S to T?.
>
> Evaluation of an implicit nullable conversion based on an underlying
>   conversion from S to T proceeds as follows:
>
> ·         If the nullable conversion is from S? to T?:
>
> o   If the source value is null (HasValue property is false), the
>   result is the null value of type T?.
>
> o   Otherwise, the conversion is evaluated as an unwrapping from S? to
>   S, followed by the underlying conversion from S to T, followed by a
>   wrapping (§4.1.10) from T to T?.
>
> ·         If the nullable conversion is from S to T?, the conversion
>   is evaluated as the underlying conversion from S to T followed by a
>   wrapping from T to T?.

Comment: beyond this explanation theres still this line `(int?)s` which DO related to inheritance/boxing era....but it works and that is the thing which i dont understant.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I don't really understand. A conversion exists from `short` to `int` (that's true in C, Java, and pretty much everywhere else), and the C# spec describes how to take that conversion and make it work on nullable types. (I added the relevant excerpt above.)

Comment: @sblom I think you should `double-bold` the paragraph above saying `The important point here is that as isn't allowed to do anything that doesn't preserve your object's identity. An explicit cast can.` - I think that's the core to this. And as for casting allowed, I agree, that's clear to me (`as` wasn't really), and as Eric said there's no arithmetics on short-s (doesn't really matter to this but it's more easier to understand, to me at least, the conversion), it converts to int.

Comment: Actually the reason `as int?` doesn't compile is because that is not a valid syntax. C# does not attempt to allow `as` with nullable values; the compiler doesn't attempt to make such a cast possible. For example, I was thinking "I either have a 'boxed int', or I want the result to become 'null'", but the compiler doesn't handle that.

Answer (score 4):

The example:

```
int? i = (int?)s;
```

Does compiler because a cast is you telling the compiler that you know something that it can't infer, that is, that `s` can be converted to a `int?`.

You will only get the exception at runtime if the cast is not successful.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Sorry, should have added that only in case the cast doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's cause in case of `as` failure you will be given a "valid" `null` result, so *false positive*. In second case, cast is allowed cause in case of failure it will raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that int? is just shorthand for `System.Nullable<int>` (`System.Nullable<T>` is the type).  The short type defines an explicit cast to an int, however `System.Nullable<T>` doesn't have any such explicit cast, because T could be any other value type.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this possible solution via reflection.
The idea is:

```cs
    var notNullableValue = 3;
    var someNullableType = typeof(Nullable<int>);
    var nullableValue = Activator.CreateInstance(someNullableType, new[] { notNullableValue });
```

In my case I could not use a direct cast because I was using arbitrary Types and Reflection to create an object and fill all properties.